# How to calculate latency of a circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis, flipflop, timing-analysis

Lets say we have this circuit:

[image]

tpd(AND)=5 ns, tpd(OR)=5ns, tpd(NOT)=3ns, and tcd of all gates =1ns

FlipFlops: tpcq=1ns, tccq=1ns, tsetup=1ns thold=1ns

First I want to check this circuit for hold-time violations. And then I want to calculate the latency.

What exactly is tccq and tpcq of FlipFlops? 
I understand that tcd+tccp > thold for the hold-time to be not violated. First I would look for the shortest path. This would be from the FF "D" to the FF "F". 
The tccq of which FF (D or F or both?) do I have to take in consideration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\$t_{pcq}\$ is the clock to Q propagation delay of a flip-flop. That is the amount of time to propagate the value at D to its Q, after a rising edge clock edge has appeared. Known as simply *propagation delay* or *clock to Q delay*.

\$t_{ccq}\$ is the amount of time needed for an *initial* change in output Q, due to the input D, after a rising edge clock edge has appeared. Known as *contamination delay*.

\$t_{cd} \$ and \$t_{pd} \$ are same things. But the terms used for combinational gates.

[image]

[image]

So \$t_{pcq}\$ = sum of \$t_{ccq}\$ and the amount of time for the output Q to become stable and valid, since the initial change occured. Same for \$ t_{pd} \$ and \$t_{cd}\$.

Suppose a flip-flop **A** launches the data and flip-flop **B** captures it.

- For no setup violation in the flip-flop to flip-flop path,
  $$ t_{pcq(A)} + t_{pd} + t_{setup(B)} < T_{clk} + t_{skew} $$
- For no hold violation in the flip-flop to flip-flop path,
  $$ t_{ccq(A)} + t_{cd} > t_{hold(B)} + t_{skew}  $$

In your circuit, skew is taken zero.

To check for hold violation, consider the shortest path. It is from Q through AND and OR:

Like:

[image]

To check for setup violation, consider the longest path.

[image]

Now from the above expressions, I think the answer is self-explanatory.

Comment: Thank you: That means for my example above: tccq(D) + tcd(AND) + tcd(OR) = 1+1+1=3ns > thold(F). Is this correct? And also want to calculate the latency: t_pd(NOT) + t_pd(AND) + t_pd(OR) + t_pcq(A) + t_setup(F) = 15ns Is this correct? Did I choose the right FlipFlop delays for the calculations?

Comment: yea that's it..

Answer (score 0):

In simple terms:

The parameters describe the time delays immediately following the clock edge. 
Tccq happens first and is the time delay from the clock edge until the Q output might not have changed but is potentially unstable.  Tpcq is the total delay that includes Tccq and any additional unstable period, after which the Q output is guaranteed to be stable.

Text book definitions:

Tccq: Contamination delay. The time after a clock edge that the Q output might be unstable.

Tpcq: Propagation delay. The time after the clock edge that the output Qs are guaranteed to be stable.

Full article:
(Chapter 3, p64) 
http://sceweb.uhcl.edu/koch/ceng5133/notes/ch3.pdf

Comment: Thank you for the responce. I don't understand, what the FlipFlops ("A"-"D") at the beginning are doing and what their purpose are, what theier effects are on timing and most importantly what theier effects are if I wanted to calculate the latency.

If I ignore the FlipFlops at the beginning: t_pd(NOT) + t_pd(AND) + t_pd(OR) + t_pcq("F") + t_setup("F") = 15ns